# Method with one parameter whose data type is ArrayList of Passenger

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

So, I have this method, printStats, whose parameter, pList, has a data type of ArrayList of Passenger:

```
public static void printStats(ArrayList<Passenger> pList) {
            Scanner file = new Scanner( new File( "titanic.csv" ) );
            DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat("#.0%");
            String header = file.nextLine();
        while (file.hasNextLine()){
            String gender;
            String survived;
            int count = 0;
            int males = 0;
            int females = 0;
            int survivedMales = 0;
            int survivedFemales = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<pList.length;i++) {
                if (gender.equals ("M"))
                { males++;
                    if (survived.equals("yes"))
                        survivedMales ++;}
                        else
                        {
                            females++;
                        }
                            if (survived.equals("yes"))
                                survivedFemales ++;}
                        count++
            System.out.println("Total number of passengers: " + count);
            System.out.println("Total number of male passengers: " + males);
            System.out.println("Total number of female passengers: " + females);
            System.out.println("Total number of male passengers survived: " + survivedMales);
            System.out.println("Total number of female passengers survived: " + survivedFemales);
            System.out.println("Survival rate of male passengers: " + percent.format(survivedMales/males));
            System.out.println("Survival rate of female passengers: " + percent.format(survivedFemales/females));
            }
```

I keep getting the syntax wrong in the for loop, specifically in the "i < pList.length":

```
for(int i=0; i<pList.length;i++)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of editor are you using to write Java? 
Most editors have a shortcut to align the code for you, making it easier to see where you made a mistake.

Comment: I am in Eclipse, it highlights the "length" in pList.length but I am not sure how to fix it still

Comment: autoformat in Eclipse: CTRL + SHIFT + F
That will make it easier to see your error next time.

I upvoted Code-Apprentice answer below because he answers your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [the documentation for ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). As you scroll down, you will see there is no public field named `length`, so `pList.length` is invalid. This is what Eclipse is complaining about. Instead, you will find there is a method named [`size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size--). So you need to replace `pList.length` with `pList.size()`.